# To find ORM app for OSX

Tags: macos, database, diagrams

I would like to have an app for OSX which can make [Object-Role Models](http://www.ormfoundation.org/), similar as [this one.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185626/why-does-many-to-many-data-structure-require-two-additional-tables/1185631#1185631)

I use currently Top Coder's UML tool. However, it has some weaknesses: I cannot change the order of columns easily and it is time-consuming to label arrows.

**What is the best ORM -tool for OSX?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only tool I have found for doing any type of diagrams in OSX that really works is [OmniGraffle](http://www.omnigroup.com/applications/OmniGraffle/). It is not free but well worth the price.

However [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_object-relational_mapping_software) Wikipedia entry lists a few different options for various platforms and development languages.